# Wrapping text around a div/ iframe/ image

Tags: html, css, text, formatting, word-wrap

I need to wrap some text around a div (containing an  iframe of infogr.am). This is the code I have right now:

```
BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH 

<div align="right" padding-left="1px" width="250" height="500" float="right">

  <iframe src="//e.infogr.am/-1684823382_1377121261" width="250" height="500"
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" float="right"></iframe>

</div>
BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH
```

But every time I run this, the text stays on the top and bottom of the infogr.am div. What I need is infogr.am div should be aligned right and the text should be wrapping around it (i.e. on the top of it, on the left side of it, and under it). 
What am I doing wrong? Maybe is the  positioned as absolute? Any suggestions?

Comment: Which text are you reffering to?

Comment: I omitted it out of the code because my advisor would not be happy if I included it. Ill put in some blah blahs.

Comment: So where you want to place this blah blah blah

Comment: I want it around the divs. The div is aligned right, and I have text above the div, which is working fine, and I have text below the div, but I need it on the left of it as well. Right now its going above and below, but the text that is supposed to go to the left is going below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="float: right; width: 0px; height: 100px"></div>
<div style="float: right; clear: right"><iframe src="//e.infogr.am/-1684823382_1377121261" width="250" height="500"
  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" float="right"></iframe></div>
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
```

you can see it working in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7t8HR/

Goodluck